# Object.ToString() returning erroneous value

Tags: c#

If my Object value is for example 1.0, .ToString() is returning 1 and not 1.0.

But if the value is for example 1.5,  .ToString() returns 1.5.

Why this behaviour in c#?

NOTE: Object is a Double Value in this case.

Comment: It's not erroneous. Hint: What is the result of `1d == 1.00d`? Now, you can specify *specific formatting* to get the desired text results ..

Comment: Why do people have to vote down questions of beginners. Is this your way to say "you're a noob" ? The question is good formulated and it is clear what he asks. So I'll give you the point(s) back.

Answer (score 3):

It's not "erroneous", it is the default format of the actual data type.

If you want it to always be 1.0, then you need to format it as so.

```
String.Format("{0:0.0}", myObject);
or
((double)myObject).ToString("0.0");
```

Answer (score 2):

Why would 1.0 return 1.0 and not say 1.00? 1.23 will return two decimal places as well, right?

C# (and my guess is most other languages as well) will print out decimal places, if they are significant. A bunch of zeroes after the decimal point are not significant, they don't change the value of the number.

Comment: This is often the default behavior, yes.

Answer (score 1):

It's because [Double.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hfd35ad%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) uses the "G", Generic Format, specifier by default.  This means that numbers are converted to their most compact form, including this rule:

> The result contains a decimal point if required, and trailing zeros
>   after the decimal point are omitted.

Source: [MSDN: Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#GFormatString)

Answer (score 0):

please check the documentation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hfd35ad(v=vs.110).aspx

this is the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Try `value.ToString("F1")`

[Standart Numeric Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)